# Trying to find a faster way than RegEX to find URL's in an NSString... Any ideas?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, xcode, cocoa-touch

I have an `NSString` that comes from an HTML page that is 37014 characters long and has about 20 URLs scattered in it. I use this code to find the URLs and place them in an `NSArray`:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"(?:([^:/?#]+):)?(?://([^/?#]*))?([^?#]*\\.(?:jpg|gif|png))(?:\\?([^#]*))?(?:#(.*))?"
                                                                       options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive
                                                                         error:&error];
NSArray *matches = [regex matchesInString:final
                                  options:0
                                    range:NSMakeRange(0, [final length])];
```

The problem is that the code takes a good 5 seconds to execute even on an iPhone 4S. It's just too slow for one page... and I need to go through 20 HTML pages!

Is there a faster way? Perhaps `NSScanner` or `NSRange`? Anyone have any creative ideas?

Comment: Just a question - are you 100% sure that it's the above code taking 5 seconds to run?

Comment: Roughly 5 seconds... maybe 4. But yes, on a device it's taking forever. On the Simulator it's pretty fast because it's running on the computer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Look into [NSDataDetector](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSDataDetector_Class/Reference/Reference.html) with `NSTextCheckingTypeLink`.

Comment: Works WAY faster than what I had. Thanks so much! I used [[myString pathExtension] isEqualToString:@"jpg"] to detect if the URL ended in the extensions I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

Your regex is a bit extreme.  It does not fail soon enough for stuff that you can probably be sure is not a match.  From a cursory view, it looks like your are doing an almost N^2 search of the entire string.  You should strive to eliminate matches as early on as possible.

Do you really expect your URL to start on a non-word boundary?

Your regex is trying to be too general.  Analyze your data, and see if you really expect to parse URLs that are so freeform.  In the end, you are better off with several regular expressions that fail early than one so complex that it almost matches everything.

Also, make sure you do this in the background thread that is downloading the data.  Your search should not take long, compared to the download - though 5 seconds to search 37k bytes...  I could almost do that with my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

AutoHyperlinks (https://bitbucket.org/sholt/autohyperlinks2/overview) is a pretty excellent library for this purpose.